# Testing UDP Locally C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, udp

I am writing a mono C# application that needs to use UDP. I was writing my test suite so that I could make sure packets are received properly with NUnit.

I made a minimal working example with a `UdpCom` class that is supposed to just listen right now and print out the bytes it receives in the call back method.

My minimal `UdpCom` class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace UdpPractice
{
    public class UdpState
    {
        public UdpClient client;
        public IPEndPoint endpoint;
        public UdpState(UdpClient c, IPEndPoint iep)
        {
            this.client = c;
            this.endpoint = iep;
        }
    }
    public class UdpCom
    {
        public UdpState uState;
        public UdpClient uClient;
        public IPAddress address;
        public int port;
        public IPEndPoint uEndpoint;

        public UdpCom (IPAddress address, int port)
        {
            uEndpoint = new IPEndPoint (address, port);
            uClient = new UdpClient (uEndpoint);
            uState = new UdpState (uClient, uEndpoint);
            uClient.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(RxCallback), uState);
        }

        public void RxCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            UdpState rState = (UdpState)(result.AsyncState);
            UdpClient rClient = rState.client;
            IPEndPoint rEndPoint = rState.endpoint;
            byte[] rxBytes = rClient.EndReceive (result, ref rEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine ("Received Bytes ___________________________");
            Console.WriteLine (rxBytes.ToString ());

            rClient.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(RxCallback), rState);
        }
    }
}
```

My simple test instantiates this class and then sends it a dummy packet of bytes. I am not testing the result right now, just placing a break point in my `RxCallback` method.

This is my NUNIT test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UdpPractice;

namespace UdpTest
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test ()]
        public void TestCase ()
        {
            // Setup Receiver
            IPAddress address = new IPAddress (new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });
            int port = 14580;
            UdpCom com = new UdpCom (address, port);
            com.uClient.Connect (com.uEndpoint);
            // Set up sender
            UdpClient sender = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint (address, port));
            sender.Connect (address, port);

            // Dummy Data
            byte [] dummyData = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5};

            sender.Send (dummyData, dummyData.Length);
            Thread.Sleep (100);

            // Close
            sender.Close ();
            com.uClient.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Issue** is that when I'm in the `RxCallback` method on the line that I'm trying to retrieve the bytes I am getting this exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException has been thrown
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
```

I want to be able to store these bytes in a queue in my `UdpCom` class but I am having trouble accessing them in the first place.

I may be failing to udner stand some basic UDP concepts as well here but it seems pretty straght forward.

The udp examples I have been following are:

- https://yal.cc/cs-dotnet-asynchronous-udp-example/
- https://www.codeproject.com/articles/132623/basic-udp-receiver

*EDIT* 
I updated my class and tests as follows so I don't use the local loopback. But I am still getting the same exception.
`UdpCom` is now:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace UdpPractice
{
    public class UdpState
    {
        public UdpClient client;
        public IPEndPoint endpoint;
        public UdpState(UdpClient c, IPEndPoint iep)
        {
            this.client = c;
            this.endpoint = iep;
        }
    }
    public class UdpCom
    {
        public UdpState uState;
        public UdpClient uClient;
        public IPAddress address;
        public int port;
        public IPEndPoint uEndpoint;

        public UdpCom (IPAddress address, int port)
        {
            uEndpoint = new IPEndPoint (address, port);
            uClient = new UdpClient (uEndpoint);
            uState = new UdpState (uClient, uEndpoint);
            uClient.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(RxCallback), uState);
        }

        public void RxCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            UdpState rState = (UdpState)(result.AsyncState);
            UdpClient rClient = rState.client;
            IPEndPoint rEndPoint = rState.endpoint;
            byte[] rxBytes = rClient.EndReceive (result, ref rEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine ("Received Bytes ___________________________");
            Console.WriteLine (rxBytes.ToString ());

            rClient.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(RxCallback), rState);
        }
    }
}
```

and the test is:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UdpPractice;

namespace UdpTest
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test ()]
        public void TestCase ()
        {
            // Setup Receiver
            IPAddress address = new IPAddress (new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 161 });
            int port = 14580;
            UdpCom com = new UdpCom (IPAddress.Any, port);
            // com.uClient.Connect (com.uEndpoint);
            // Set up sender
            UdpClient sender = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint (address, port));
            sender.Connect (address, port);

            // Dummy Data
            byte [] dummyData = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5};

            sender.Send (dummyData, dummyData.Length);
            Thread.Sleep (100);

            // Close
            sender.Close ();
            com.uClient.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another resource you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19787486/5233410

Comment: You can only have one connection with the same 3 properties : Source IP, Destination IP, Port number.  When connecting locally you have to make sure the client and server aren't using the same 3 properties,  The solution is to have the server listen on IPAny and the client to connect to the IP address of the PC.  You are using the LoopBack address of the PC 127.0.0.1 which normally is LocalHost.  The Net library doesn't allow the loopback IP to be used by the client and will give exceptions.

Comment: So I took out my `com.uClient.Connect (com.uEndpoint);` line and made the `com` client listen on IPAny with `UdpCom com = new UdpCom (IPAddress.Any, port);` and the sender UdpClient connect on 192.168.1.161. I am getting the same exception. I updaded my question to reflect the changes.

Comment: This behavior is expected. The only way to interrupt an asynchronous socket operation is to close the socket. When you do, any pending callbacks will be invoked, but the socket will already be disposed. The solution is to do a `catch (ObjectDisposedException)` around the `.EndReceive`. And yes, I know that normally you're not supposed to catch `ObjectDisposedException`, but otherwise you have to add a thread-safe flag to detect the disposal, which is more complicated for little gain. See als [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310417/h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was struggling with a basic misunderstanding with how to communicate with UDP.

UdpCom:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UdpPractice
{
    public class UdpState
    {
        public UdpClient client;
        public IPEndPoint endpoint;
        public UdpState(UdpClient c, IPEndPoint iep)
        {
            this.client = c;
            this.endpoint = iep;
        }
    }
    public class UdpCom
    {
        public UdpState uState;
        public IPAddress address;
        public int port;
        public IPEndPoint uEndpoint;
        public bool receiveFlag;
        public List<byte[]> rxBytesBuffer;

        public UdpCom (IPAddress address, int port)
        {
            uEndpoint = new IPEndPoint (address, port);
            // uClient = new UdpClient (uEndpoint);
            uState = new UdpState (new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port)), uEndpoint);
            receiveFlag = false;
            uState.client.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(RxCallback), uState);
            rxBytesBuffer = new List<byte[]> ();
        }

        public void RxCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            UdpState rState = (UdpState)result.AsyncState;
            UdpClient rClient = ((UdpState)result.AsyncState).client;
            IPEndPoint rEndPoint = ((UdpState)result.AsyncState).endpoint;
            byte[] rxBytes = rClient.EndReceive (result, ref rEndPoint);
            rxBytesBuffer.Add (rxBytes);
            Console.WriteLine ("Received Bytes ___________________________");
            Console.WriteLine (rxBytes.ToString ());
            receiveFlag = true;
            rClient.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(RxCallback), result.AsyncState);
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UdpPractice;

namespace UdpTest
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test ()]
        public void TestCase ()
        {
            // Setup Listener
            int port = 14580;
            IPEndPoint locep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            // Server (Listener)
            UdpCom com = new UdpCom (IPAddress.Any, port);
            // Set up sender
            UdpClient sender = new UdpClient();
            // Dummy Data
            byte [] dummyData = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5};
            sender.Send (dummyData, dummyData.Length, locep);
            sender.Send (dummyData, dummyData.Length, locep);
            Thread.Sleep (100);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, com.receiveFlag);
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to make the listener listen to `IPAddress.Any` and then I mainly used the `Send` method with the `EndPoint` argument. I had to add the delay in there because otherwise the receive flag wasn't being set.